# Why should the same friction $f$ act throughout the part of pulley where the string touches it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

**Why should the same friction $f$ act throughout the part of pulley where the string touches it (as shown in the diagram above)?**

I rather feel that friction acting downwards on the right side of the pulley is $f_1=T_1$ (as mass of string is $0$) and friction acting downwards on the left side of the pulley $f_2=T_2$ (as mass of string is $0$) . So the equation $(f_2-f_1)R=I\alpha$ holds. So I don't think friction should be same throughout. Am I going wrong ?

Comment: What is the mass of the pulley?

Comment: @probably_someone The pulley has a mass $M$ suppose. Okay ?

Comment: You are absolutely correct if the pulley has mass.

Comment: Actually, you're correct even if the pulley doesn't have mass, come to think of it.

Comment: @probably_someone But my teacher said that "
 friction is acting only in one side on pulley which is rotating the pulley... its not equal and opposite..."

Comment: Which is precisely what you stipulate here. I see no problem with that. The teacher is referring to the *net* frictional force on the pulley.

Comment: @probably_someone Umm, so you mean that my teacher meant that "$f_1$ and $f_2$ are both downward but not equal ...and hence a net friction rotates the pulley" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51232/discussion-between-mathjack-and-probably-someone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friction is proportional to normal force, which depends on tension and curvature of the pulley.

Curvature is constant - but tension changes: thus friction will not be the same at every point.

With that said - you only care about the fact that "friction somewhere" , combined with the mass of the pulley, causes a difference in tension  between the left and right side - that should be sufficient to solve the equations of motion for this system. Unless the string is not rigid but has finite elasticity...

Comment: You said "tension" changes. How do we know the tension at each point ? I mean how do we find it mathematically?

Comment: @MathJack Google the "capstan equation"

Comment: Thank you. I found it here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OJTYHaYxzo

Comment: Floris, if you have some time, could you please answer this question ?  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/303078/why-does-a-r-alpha-hold-here (I seem to be facing a lot of problems in Rotational Dynamics :P)