# Uniform circular motion & relative velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics

Consider a car moving along a straight horizontal road at constant speed, $v$.

Also consider one of the tyres/wheel of the car. On it, there are two particles of dust $A$ and $B$ (as shown in the diagram) at the outer edge of the tire.

How would I find the velocity of each dirt particle, relative to the road?

[image: Just a diagram, showing what I'm]

Comment: Hint : What part of the wheel is moving with velocity $v$? If the wheel is not slipping against the road, what is the velocity at point A?

Comment: Um, I'd guess the whole wheel is moving at velocity, v. But if, it's not slipping against the road at A, that would perhaps mean it's at rest at A. However I don't understand how it is not slipping, I can't appreciate that.

Comment: Get hold of a wheel or disk and watch what happens as it rolls.

Comment: To imagine how it is not slipping imagine that the wheel is a gear and the floor has holes for the teeth. It is not a great analogy, but it show you that there are ways for a translating but also rotating device to move without slipping.

Answer (score 1):

*(I answered a [very similar question about rotational acceleration](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/303078/why-does-a-r-alpha-hold-here/303092#303092) the other day - you might find it useful)*

You find the velocities of the particles on the rim by remembering the expression:

$$v=R\omega$$

Some call this a *geometric bond* because it ties rotation ($\omega$) to translation ($v$).

$v$ is the speed of a particle on the rim seen from the centre.

- On a freely spinning wheel, particles on the rim move with speed $v$.
- But for a wheel touching the ground **without slipping**, there **must** be **no** motion of that rim-point that touches the ground! Instead it is the **centre** of the wheel that moves with $v$. And the opposite upper rim-point moves with $2v$.

The point is that the rim moves with $v$ at all points **seen from the centre**. So when the centre itself is moving, we have to add that to those rim-points when we look at it from outside.

---

I can see there has started a small discussion about the no-slipping of the contact-point in the comments.

The point is that the point of the wheel that touches the ground *musn't* move of the same reason that your foot touching the ground musn't move when you take a step. If your foot was slipping and sliding, you wouldn't be able to push yourself forward. Same for the wheel.

And when that touching contact-point *is* slipping (from accelerating or braking to violently e.g.), we call it *wheelspin* and you would hear a squeaking sound and maybe see smoke because of the **kinetic friction** that happens. And as you maybe know from movies, during the wheelspin the car doesn't accelerate - it only start really speeding up, when the wheelspin is over, because then the wheels grip the ground again and there is no slipping.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible way to solve the problem:

Consider the road is at rest.

The wheel rotates with an angular velocity $\dot\phi$.
For polar coordinates, we know

$$
x = r*cos(\phi) \\
y = r*sin(\phi)
$$

From this, you can calculate $\dot{x}, \dot{y}$ as a function of $\phi, \dot{\phi}$. Also, dust particle A is at $\phi = -\pi/2$ and particle B is at $\phi = \pi/2$.

To this, add the velocity $v$ with which the wheel is moving and you should have your solution.